# How to read data from forked processes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, process, system

who can give me a short example where i call some system command and then read it out with haskell and e.g. print it?

i know that i can use System.Cmd to make system commands like: nm, ls, mkdir etc.

but i dont need to call them only also i need to read it and make some operations with the readed string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key library to use is [the `process` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process), which provides [System.Process](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/1.0.1.5/doc/html/System-Process.html).

To call a command and get its output:

```
readProcess
      :: FilePath   -- command to run
      -> [String]   -- any arguments
      -> String         -- standard input
      -> IO String  -- stdout
```

Like so:

```
import System.Process

main = do
    s <- readProcess "/bin/date" [] []
    putStrLn $ "The date is " ++ s
```

which runs as:

```
The date is Fri Apr 29 09:29:29 PDT 2011
```

Answer (score 2):

[System.Process](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/process-1.0.1.5/System-Process.html) has the functions you want, specifically `readProcess`.

```
main = do
  wcOut <- readProcess "wc" ["/usr/share/dict"] []
  let numLines = read (head (words wcOut)) :: Int
  if numLines > 10 then return () else print "That's a small dictionary."
```